# My VS2012 installation appears to be missing the core Reporting functionality

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

First off, I apologize if this is the wrong forum but I strongly feel that the people who can help with this problem are in fact developers themselves... If this thread needs to be moved to an alternate site, please let me know...

We write a lot of reports using the Microsoft Reporting framework, mainly RDLC. After we upgraded to VS2012 from VS2008, I can no longer create or open RDLCs. When I try to add a new report from the "Add New Item" menu, it's not even an option. We do have DevExpress reporting installed, and I can create a new report using the DX engine, but that's not what need here. From everything I have read, reporting is core to VS and not an option, so it needs to be installed. Had we been using SSRS, then I understand we need to install reporting from the SQL installation, and not VS, but again that's not the case. We have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS2012, performing repairs of VS2012, but nothing works. Every other developer I work with hasn't had any issues like I've encountered, and they also have both DX reporting and MS reporting working side by side without issue.

I found one other [post](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/csharp/csharpide.aspx?ID=43f9ba11-728b-499a-963b-38878f36c178) on a website that highlights the same problem I am encountering. The difference is that his resolution was basically to format his machine and reinstall everything. This is totally unacceptable. My OS is Windows 7 32bit, and I have VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 installed, along with SQL 2008.

I am looking for any advice on a potential resolution for this problem. It is imperative that I get the reporting component up and running ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

Addtional Information on VS 2012 is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx

Note that there is a lot of "talk" about needing to install SQL 2012 locally to gain all the features of VS 2012 and RDLC.  There is also more chatter about you can open the Project and build but you cant modify or edit the RDLC.

We just stayed in SQL 2008 and VS 2008 land for all of our Reporting ( SSRS, RDLC ), SSIS and BIDS project work.

So...believe it or not we have 2 branches for some projects.

1 Branch is VS 2008 to work on the RDLC files.
2 Branch is a VS 2012 to work on the source code.

Yuck, and double yuck.

Keep reading if you want separate environments.

We have had similar issues and the successful installation of VS2012 beside the VS 2008 SSRS BIDS tools is to UNCHECK ANY SQL Express/Tools when you install VS 2012.

Now in your case this is to late.  So, I recommend going to repair SQL 2008 then make sure SSRS, BIDS and any other associated tools are checked and let it try to repair the installation.

The last I checked VS 2012 doesnt support SSRS or their associated report formats "RDL" you will have to stay in VS 2008 and/or SQL BIDS 2008.

Best results may include the following steps.

1. Try repairing SQL 2008 and SSRS and BIDS.
2. Uninstall VS 2012 then repeat step 1.
3. IF you install VS 2012 UNCHECK any options to install any SQL Express or SQL type tools.

I did 3. and have had no issues but this was after 2-3 DBA I know crashed and burned by not unchecking these SQL options during the VS 2012 install.